# Spark Dataframe timestamp column manipulation failing without any error message

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```py
aggregate = aggregate.withColumn('DaysSinceFirstUsage', when(months_between(current_date(), col('FirstUsage')) > 120, - (sys.maxsize - 1)).otherwise(days_between(current_date(), col('FirstUsage')))

aggregate = aggregate.withColumn('DaysSinceLastUsage', when(months_between(current_date(), col('LastUsage')) > 120, - (sys.maxsize - 1)).otherwise(days_between(current_date(), col('LastUsage')))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silly mistake :)
Closing bracket at the end was missing and datediff was wrongly written as days_between. Query running fine after correction.

```
aggregate = aggregate.withColumn('DaysSinceFirstUsage', when(months_between(current_date(), col('FirstUsage')) > 120, - (sys.maxsize - 1)).otherwise(datediff(current_date(), col('FirstUsage'))))
aggregate = aggregate.withColumn('DaysSinceLastUsage', when(months_between(current_date(), col('LastUsage')) > 120, - (sys.maxsize - 1)).otherwise(datediff(current_date(), col('LastUsage'))))
```